# Disable External Microphone

Tags: microphone

I have a Samsung Galaxy A5 2017 and use it to listen to music in my car thru an aux cable.

The problem is, when the aux is connected to the phone, its detect an "external microphone" wich capture no sound at all (because my car dont have an external mic).

So, when I try to make a voice record or send a voice message on whatsapp, there is no sound recorded.

There is a way to disable the phone from using an external mic?
I downloaded the app "soundabout", its solves the problem but create others (like pausing/unpausing when aux is connected), so I still need a full fix.

Ty!